# changing render size of my filter shows me error

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

i have tried to make some stuff in my application made by c++ directshow 
i want to change the default render size (driver campture size) from 640x480
but it tells me that this size is not available 
but in amcap it works how is that  ??
i have tried to stop the render by using `mediaControl->stop();` but it seems that it does not work 
this is a screen capture 
[enter link description here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ST36bZ97eXI/UFhZfOR7OMI/AAAAAAAAADs/uqvpkw25Y8Q/s1600/filter.png)

you can find out more about it in my blog 
[enter link description here](http://mydirectshow.blogspot.com/)

ok i have added some code here

```
hr=pConfig->QueryInterface(IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages,(void**) &pSpec);//," page ");
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
        hr=pSpec->GetPages(&cauuid);
        if( SUCCEEDED(hr) && cauuid.cElems>0){

            this->releaseRender();
            checkIt( OleCreatePropertyFrame(this->owner, 30, 30, NULL, 1,
                (IUnknown **)&pConfig, cauuid.cElems,
                (GUID *)cauuid.pElems, 0, 0, NULL),"stuff ");

            CoTaskMemFree(cauuid.pElems);

        }
```

but when i click  like what to change it says u can't do this stuff
i'm using a IbaseFilter like source filter i' have tried to remove this filter from 
iGraphBuilder

```
this->graphB->RemoveFilter(this->srcFilter);
```

Comment: You need to provide more information and code examples before somebody can help you! What Screen-Capture Filter are you using? How do you tried changing the render size? Normaly you can only do this, if the Source-Filter is not connected! Before you code some FilterGraphs try your actions manualy with GraphEdit or [GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/). Everything you can do with these tools can also be done by code and they help to understand the working with the DirectShow Framework.

Comment: i'm using IGraphBuilder filter and connected with ICaptureGraphBuilder2